# IF Statement to change codes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data to change in four columns. They are vendor codes, and each one has a specific PIC, LS_Name, Supplier Code and Group.  I have been trying to write an IF statement to do the same thing, but I have something out of place. Where is my mistake?

```
Sub Change_Codes()

Dim Range As Range
Range = ("E2:E3000")

If Range = "MU999" Then Range = "R. Martinez"
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: is there a problem with your code? What is the actual question? If you're asking which way is better the IF or Select case then your question is off-topic as it would be primarily opinion based.

Comment: So you want to ask whether people think `Case` is better or `If`? In that case this is not a good question, as SO discourages questions asking for opinion. Perhaps change it to asking how to achieve the similar result using `Case`?

Comment: Thank you; I have edited the question. I hope this is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but this is one way of *replacing text MU999 with R. Martinez within rows 2 and 3000 in column E*

```
Sub Main()

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("E2:E3000")
        If StrComp(c, "MU999", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            c = "R. Martinez"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

---

so if you have had more conditions you could either use `If-else` or `Select Case`

If-else example

```
Sub Main()

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("E2:E3000")
        If StrComp(c, "MU999", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            c = "R. Martinez"
        ElseIf StrComp(c, "MU111", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            c = "replaced with M. Martinez"
        ElseIf StrComp(c, "MU666", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            c = "666 is not evil!"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

and `Select case`

```
Sub Main()

    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("E2:E3000")

        Select Case UCase(c)
            Case "MU999"
                c = "R. Martinez"
            Case "MU111"
                c = "replaced with M. Martinez"
            Case "MU666"
                c = "666 is not evil!"
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: (`StrComp` returns true when the strings are *not* equal.)

Comment: @rdhs oh yea forgot the 0 :)

Comment: The Select Case worked like magic. Thank you very much!!!